# ASP.NET 4 pie chart number and percent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, mschart

I've been Googling for an answer for quite some time but have been unable to find what I am looking to accomplish with the MS ASP.NET 4 Pie chart.  There are many answers to achieve one or the other, but it appears that no conclusive answer exists to have both a numeric value AND a percentage value.  Here is an example of what it is that I am trying to accomplish:

```
          -------------
         /           / \
        /           /   \
       /   8       /     \
      /           /       \
     /  38.10%   /         \
    |           /           |
     \ ________/           /
      \           13      /
       \                 /
        \      61.90%   /
         \             /
          -------------
```

I am able to get either number individually, but how does one achieve displaying both values simultaneously?  C# and/or VB.NET solutions are equally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#VALX #PERCENT{P0}";

'#VALX' shows the x value and so combining with the '#PERCENT{P0}' generates a label like this "winners 32%" where "winners" is my x value.